# Code flow with the combination of stream, collect and forEach in java

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, java-stream

I have come across code in my companies project, which goes like this

```
void pAccount(List<Account> accounts) {
    accounts.stream()
        .filter(o->getKey(o) != null)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getKey))
        .forEach(this::pAccounts);
}

private Key getKey(Account account) {
    return keyRepository.getKeyById(account.getId());
}

private void pAccounts(Key key , List<Account> accounts) {
    //Some Code
}
```

While debugging we came to the conclusion that `pAccount(List<Account> accounts)` calls `pAccounts(Key key , List<Account> accounts`.

I have tried to find similar examples online but found nothing that matches this behavior.

I want to know if this is some kind of functionality in streams that allows us to do that or it's something else.

Comment: Altough i might be wrong, but i would not recommend to create `n` queries for `getKey`, but rather collect all ids first, then fetch all keys in one query and create a new stream that operates on the result.

Comment: @Naman why did you remove the [java-8] tag?

Comment: @Andronicus The version tags have been always debatable(wouldn't be able to debate much). So unless placed by the person asking or relevant from the code(specific API) in the question I think version-specific tags should not be required. For example, what if OP might be looking for a Java-14 solution here? So I would suggest adding version tags only if the asker puts that as a bound or the API in code are not relevant to any other version. It is still up to you to choose though.

Comment: @Naman got it, thanks for the clarification, have a great day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you're referring to is called in `forEach(this::pAccounts)`. 
It's because `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getKey))` returns a `Map`.

The `forEach` on `Map`, according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), takes a `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V>`, where the first parameter is the key of type `K` and the second - a value of type `V`.

So this `forEach` is not a method on `Stream`, but on `Map`.

Comment: does `this::` calls the method, in my particular scenario

Comment: @abhi314 `forEach` calls the method that is passed as a lambda, `::` is a method reference - a syntactinc sugar for `(k, v) -> this.pAccounts(k, v)`.